# Vuejs is not detected

Tags: php, css, html, vue.js, bootstrap-4

Hey everyone please help! Vue js is not detected on my page. I have no idea why. I've built plenty of vueapps in the past and have never had a problem before. I wonder does bootstrap js conflict with vuejs? I load up the page and when I try to go into the chrome dev tools it says vuejs is not  detected. Mind boggling! Any ideas?

```
 <?php ob_start(); session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['activated'])) {
    $activated = $_SESSION['activated'];
  }

  if (isset($activated) && $activated == 0) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Please activate your account before signing in. ");';
    echo 'window.location.href = "resendoptions.php?userName=' . $_SESSION[username] . '";';
    echo '</script>';
  }

  if (isset($_SESSION['success']) and $_SESSION['success'] == 1) {
    $success = 1;
  }
  else {
    $success = 0;
  }

?>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        nav a{
            color: white
        }
        nav {background-color: #1c71b9; }
        .navbar-toggle{border: 3px solid white;}
        .icon-bar{background-color: white;}
        .navbar-brand:hover{background-color: white;
        color: #1c71b9;
        }
        body{margin-top: 50px;}
        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p{
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
        }
        .row + .row{margin-top: 20px;}
        .itemHeading{font-weight: bold;}
        .icon{display: block; max-width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;}
        .descriptionHeading{margin-top: 20px; text-align: center;}
        .descriptionSection{background-color: lightgray;}
        .mainDescriptionHeading{text-align: center;}
        .descriptionParagraph{text-align: center;}
        .centerDescriptionButton{padding-bottom: 20px;}
        .first-slide video{width: 100%;}
        .second-slide video{width: 100%;}
        .third-slide video{width: 100%;}
        .first-slide{width: 100%;}
        .second-slide{width: 100%;}
        .third-slide{width: 100%;}
        #myCarousel{margin-top: 50px;}
        .card{width: 100%; margin-bottom: 30px; box-shadow: 0 0 5px; padding: 15px;}
        .card video{width:100%;}
        .card-title{font-weight: bold;}

        .error{color: red;}
          .success{color: green;}
          .tooltip {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            padding-right: 5px;
            font-size: 20px;
          }
          .tooltip .tooltiptext {
              visibility: hidden;
              width: 240px;
              background-color: red;
              color: white;
              text-align: center;
              border-radius: 6px;
              padding: 5px 0;
              font-size: 15px;
              /* Position the tooltip */
              position: absolute;
              z-index: 1;
              top: -5px;
              left: 105%;
          }

          .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
              visibility: visible;
          }
          blue{color: darkblue; background-color: darkblue;}

    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--vuejs-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">My Site</a>
        </div><!--end .navbar-header-->
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li v-show="admin==1"><a href="adminMenu.php">Admin</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Subscriptions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Templates</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Stock</a></li>
            <li v-show="sesloggedin==0"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Login</a></li>
            <li v-show="sesloggedin==1"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Signup</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--end #navbar-->
     </div><!--end container-->
    </nav>
     <div class="container">
      <div id="loginModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <!--modal header-->
                <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
                <h2 class="modal-title">Login</h2>
                </div>
                <!--modal body-->
                <div class="modal-body">
                <form role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username">Username/Email</label>
                        <input v-on:click="error=0; loginsub=0;" v-model="userName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username/Email" id="username" name="userName">
                        <a href="#">Forgot Username</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input v-on:click="error=0; loginsub=0;" v-model="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password">
                        <a href="#">Forgot Password</a>
                    </div>
                    <div v-show="error==1 || userName.length<=7 && loginsub==1 || password.length<=7 && loginsub==1"><small class="error">Username/Email or password was incorrect...Try again</small>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <!--modal footer-->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                <button v-on:click="submit();" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <script>
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      userName: '',
      password: '',
      success: '<?php echo $success;?>',
      error: '',
      showPopUp: '',
      loginsub: '',
      response: [],
      sesusername: '<?php if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {echo $_SESSION['username'];}?>',
      sesemail: '<?php if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) { echo $_SESSION['email'];}?>',
      sesloggedin: '<?php if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {echo $_SESSION['loggedin'];}?>',
      sesfirstname: '<?php if (isset($_SESSION['firstname'])) {echo $_SESSION['firstname'];}?>',
      seslastname: '<?php if (isset($_SESSION['lastname'])) {echo $_SESSION['lastname'];}?>',
      sesphone: '<?php if (isset($_SESSION['phonenumber'])) {echo $_SESSION['phonenumber'];}?>',
      sescompanyname: '<?php  if (isset($_SESSION['companyname'])) {echo $_SESSION['companyname'];}?>',
      admin: '<?php if (isset($_SESSION['admin'])) {echo $_SESSION['admin'];}?>'
    },
    created: function() {
      this.showPopUp = "<?php if(isset($_GET['showLoginForm']) and $_GET['showLoginForm']==1){echo true;} else{echo false;}?>";
      this.loginsub = 0;
    },
    methods: {
      popUp: function() {
        this.showPopUp = !this.showPopUp;
      },
      submit: function() {
        this.loginsub = 1
        if (this.userName.length >= 8 && this.password.length >= 8) {
          var jsonString = JSON.stringify({
            userName: this.userName,
            password: this.password
          });
          $.ajax({
            url: "login.php",
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: jsonString,
            success: function(data) {
              var vueapp = this;
              vueapp.response = data;
              vueapp.error = data.error;
              if(data.showPopUp==false){
                  $('#loginModal').modal('hide');
              }
              if (data.success == 1) {
                window.location = window.location.href.split("?")[0];
              }
              console.log(data);
            }.bind(this)
          });
        }
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: are you using a vue devtool?

Comment: yes I am using vue Dev tool

Comment: Looking at this piece of code seems that you don't need Vuejs at all.

Comment: yes I do v-on:click="submit();" I would like to use vuejs can i do it?

Comment: Hopefully, Mr O'Keefe never signs up..

Comment: @codernoob5 : See your chrome console for errors. the data sesusername and the following have a escaping issue

Answer (score 0):

For the vue devtools to work, there should be atleast single instance of Vue on the page.

Since your data has an escaping issue. Your Vue instance is never created

convert from

```
 sesusername: '<?php if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {echo $_SESSION['username'];}?>',
```

to

```
 sesusername: '<?php if (isset($_SESSION["username"])) {echo $_SESSION["username"];}?>',
```